# why the below mentioned program don't give null reference exception?

Tags: c#-4.0

Why this program output is "1". But it should have given "Null Reference exception" because I set it to null in xyz() method.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        b.xyz(a);
        Console.WriteLine(a.x);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    class A
    {
        public int x = 1;
    }
    class B
    {
        public void xyz(A a)
        {
            a = null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set a *copy of the variable `a`* to `null`. This copy is created implicitly when the method `xyz` is called; that's because by default arguments in method calls are passed by value.

To get the exception you would need to pass the method's argument by reference:

```
public void xyz(ref A a)
{
    a = null;
}
```

and then

```
b.xyz(ref a);
```

There is documentation on the subject on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z.aspx).

Comment: But class objects are passed by reference by default. why do we need to set by "ref"?

Comment: @user3177199: They are not *passed by reference*, rather they are *references that are passed by value*. It's an important distinction.